# Limit of $n a_n$ for positive, decreasing $(a_n)$ and convergent $\sum a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have the following question, and a hint but I am not sure how to go with it. I have an intuition that tells me it's right but I don't know how to prove it.

Is it somehow related to Cauchy's condensation test ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sum a_n$ converges with positive terms there exists $N$ such that if $m > n > N$ we have

$$\sum_{k = n+1}^{m}a_k < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Since $a_n$ is decreasing we have for $n > N$

$$2na_{2n}<2\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}a_k <2\frac{\epsilon}{2}= \epsilon$$ 
$$(2n+1)a_{2n+1}< 2(n+1)a_{2n+1}< 2\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n+1}a_k  < 2\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.$$

Hence, $na_n \to 0$ since both subsequences with even and odd indexes converge to $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the hint, what does it have to do with convergence, do I use Cauchy's condensation test with that ?

Comment: No its a more direct approach: Since $\sum a_n$ converges there is $N$ such that $\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}a_k < \epsilon$ for $m > n > N$. Then show $2na_{2n}, (2n+1)a_{2n+1} \to 0$

Comment: Okay I'm getting there, I see where you want to go, how do I show that it converges to 0 though ?

Comment: The subsequences with even and odd indexes both converge to $0$.  I'll expand above.

Comment: Okay I see it now, could you please re-write it to sum up ? I have to write it down and I don't want to forget something / make a mistake.

Comment: Added details above