# Terms of a monotone, convergent series must be $o(1/n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a non-negative, *non-increasing* sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n<\infty$. I want to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\{nx_n\}=0.$$ I’ve definitely seen this question asked on this forum before, but I’m unable to find it now. Any reference or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: *Hint.* Can you check that $2(a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} + \cdots + a_n) \geq n a_n$?

Comment: Answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1719134/148510

Comment: Another interesting question is if $o(1/ (n \log n))$ necessary.http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1719134/148510

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1697300/148510

Comment: @RRL Thank you, that’s precisely the thread I’ve been looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. The second link has a very nice answer by @Etienne

Comment: [If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of strictly positive numbers and if $\sum{a_n}$ is convergent, show that $\lim{na_n}=0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/369669)